# Document load event not fired in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-component, html-imports

We have an application using WebComponents V0 spec. We use Polymer's vulcanizer to put together all our components into a single importable HTML and import it from the main application page (HTML imports). Noticed an issue in Chrome recently (not sure about the version-since) that document doesn't load on the first attempt. On subsequent reloads from cache, the document gets loaded successfully. With cache disabled, the document doesn't load again. The browser tab just keeps spinning and there is no DOMContentLoaded or Load event markers in the network panel.

How do we know what is going on in Chrome? What are the typical steps to be followed when document `load` is not happening?

Here are the things that I can confirm:

- There is no infinite loop in code. Browser main thread seems to be idle
- There is no pending resource to be loaded in the network panel
- There is no activity on the `Performance` panel of Chrome devtools
- Tried toggling the polyfill
- Issue seems to happen only when webcomponents are used in the page
- Document's `readyState` was `loading`. All other HTML imports on the page had status as `complete`
- There is no luck with Incognito mode as well

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary. Try the older portable versions of Chrome. Try reporting it on https://crbug.com and provide a demo page (you can ask to send it privately to a developer).

Comment: what code did you write to import the file?

Comment: link rel="import"

Comment: that won't work with little code